# microSD read-only for 3rd party apps after factory reset - Lenovo A1010, Android 5.1

Tags: sd-card, permissions, lenovo

I did a factory reset on said phone due to a malware infection, used APKPure to install the handful of apps that I need (no Google account activated on phone after reboot) and now I observe the following:

- no third-party app (OpenCamera, ASTRO File Manager etc.) can write anything to the microSD
- built-in SW *can* write to the microSD without an issue: the built-in com.mediatek.filemanager app can create directories on the card and I can wipe the microSD clean from Storage management in Settings
- if I take out the card and mount it on a computer, it works just fine, read and write

The phone is not rooted and I'm hesitant to root it because of complexity or safety of the procedure.

I've tried formatting the card on the computer, on the phone, playing around with Developer options etc. but nothing seems to work. It doesn't look like a hardware malfunction or a filesystem error, since built-in apps seem to be able to write to the card just fine. I don't have another card at hand to check that it's not the card, though.

What can I do to enable writing? Google's/Lenovo's handcuffs regarding HW *I* supposedly own are really frustrating.